# npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL while installing frontity

Tags: npx, frontity

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npx frontity create my-app && cd my-app

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "wolf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\4608" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mystic wolf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-13T06_42_07_591Z-debug.log
Install for frontity@latest failed with code 1

i have tried clearing npm cache,
upgrading npm version
but cant solve it.
i feel like there is something is wrong with package.json
how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is a problem of npx when the user folder contains an space (`Mystic wolf`)

You need to move the npm cache to a folder without spaces.

First, open `cmd` as Administrator.

- Search for `cmd`
- Right click
- Choose “Run as Administrator”
- Enter your password

[run-as-administrator-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbxdC.png)

Then enter these commands in the console:

```
> mklink /J "C:\Users\mystic-wolf" "C:\Users\Mystic wolf"
> npm config set cache C:\Users\mystic-wolf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
> npm config set prefix C:\Users\mystic-wolf\AppData\Roaming\npm
> npm cache clean --force
```

You have more info here: https://community.frontity.org/t/error-running-npx/512/8.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command:

```
npm i @frontity/core
```

It Works.